# Cannot run Git from windows command line?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, git

I have an unusual problem. I am not able to run git from the commanline:

```
c:\> git
(popup)
c:\>
```

Popup:

[image: Looking for solution]
[image: No solution found]

I also found this (non-) info in the windows logs:

[image: windows application log]

**How can I get git to run from commandline?**

What I've tried/checked:

1. I checked the environment path. The correct path is there.
2. I re-installed using the latest git binary.
3. I ran the binary directly from the folder. It runs the help and quickly closes.
4. I tried installing older versions of git (1.9.2 and 1.8.0). Same error as before.

More info:

I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit.
Git runs from powershell but not cmd.

Comment: Maybe somehow related to what Cygwin’s `autorebase` solves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended resolving this. It's the simplest things that make you pull your hair out...

1. uninstall
2. REBOOT (d'oh)
3. re-install

As to what caused this in the first place, I have no idea.